# UDP Java, dont return right case answer

Tags: java, udp

My UDP Java program don’t return right sentence from Cases. 
Program should return 4 different answers for 4 different questions.
But only answer I receiving is default answer “Answer not found"
I think there is some issue when Server trying to pass “sentence” to cases method
Do I missing something in code?

SERVER Class

```
package pac1;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("UDP Server: Started");
        DatagramSocket serverSocket =new DatagramSocket(9878);
        byte[]  receiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[]  sendData = new byte[1024];
        while (true){
            DatagramPacket  receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                    receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            System.out.println("UDP Server Received: "+sentence);
            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            int port = receivePacket.getPort();
            String out;
            out=getAnswer(sentence);

            System.out.println(sentence);
            sendData= out.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,
            sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
            System.out.println("UDP Server Sending to Client: "+out);
            }

        }
    private static String getAnswer(String sentence) {
        String out;
        switch(sentence) {  
        case "A" : out =  "65";
        break;
        case "B" : out =  "66";
        break;
        case "C" : out =  "67";
        break;
        case "D" : out =  "68";
        break;

        default: out = "Answer not found";
        break;

        } 
        return out;
    }
    }
```

CLIENT Class

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("UDP Client: Started");

         String url = "rmi:///";
            System.out.println("Enter Question: ");
            Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);
            String sentence = myinput.nextLine();

        DatagramSocket clientSocket =new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        byte[]  sendData = new byte[1024];
        byte[]  receiveData = new byte[1024];
        sendData =sentence.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket  sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,
                sendData.length, IPAddress, 9878);
        System.out.println("UDP Client: Sending "+ sentence);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                receiveData.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
        System.out.println("UDP Client: Received From Server; "+ modifiedSentence);
        clientSocket.close();
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having this issue is likely due to the way you're creating the string in your server class. When you have a packet initialized to receive 1024 bytes of data, and you send fewer that 1024 bytes, the rest of the array is padded with zeros. This causes your string to have empty space at the end. The most simple solution to this problem would probably be to call:

```
sentence.trim();
```

after you convert your received data to a string on the server side.

Comment: A better approach is to use the actual length `String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());`